# INSERT anidado en MySql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Quisiera saber si se puede realizar un insert anidado como si fuera un query anidado, pondré un ejemplo con una mini tabla

```
   __________                _________
  | Persona  |              |  Orden  |
  |——————————|              |————————-|  
  |idPersona |              |idOrden  |
  |nombre    |              |fecha    |
  |apellidos |              |hora     |
   ——————————               |asunto   |
                            |idPersona|
                             —————————
```

Para llenar los datos de la tabla Orden necesito saber el idPersona y en el mismo formulario lleno los datos de persona sin el ID ya que es autoincrement como lleno la tabla orden?
Pensaba en algo así
—————————————————————————————————
INSERT INTO persona P, orden O (P.nombre, P.apellidos, O.fecha, O.hora, O.asunto) VALÚES(“nombre”, “apellidos”, 06/07/2020, “asunto”) WHERE P.idPersona = O.idPersona;
—————————————————————————————————
Obviamente estoy mal porque ya lo intenté pero no encuentro la forma de llenar las dos tablas al mismo tiempo tomando en cuanta el Id es autoincrementable por mysql.
Les agradezco colegas, saludos.

Comment: Que lenguaje utilizas para el formulario? o sea al momento de insertar o tipear los datos.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿La persona en ese contexto no existe todavía? Si es así, tienes que hacer dos `INSERT`, primero de la persona, luego con `LAST_INSERT_ID` recuperas el `ID` que se habrá asignado a la persona que se acaba de insertar y los usas junto con los otros datos que ya tienes para hacer una 2ª inserción, esta vez en la tabla `Orden`.  Si la persona ya existe entonces la inserción sólo se haría en la tabla `Orden`, teniendo de ante-mano el ID de la persona, dado que ya existe.

Comment: @Santiago Estoy utilizando JSP

Comment: @A.Cedano si me funciono, gracias , quedo así INSERT INTO Persona (nombre, apellidos) VALÚES (“Juan”, “Perez”);           SELECT last_insert_id() INTO @id;            INSERT INTO Orden (fecha, hora, asunto, idPersona) VALÚES (“2020-07-06” , “17:00” , “asunto”, @id);      Pero, podrá simplificarse aún más? O hay otra manera de poder hacerlo?

Comment: @Mickey no. Cada insert va por separado. Lo que si, eso tiene que estar dentro de una transaccion, no vaya a ser que el last id no sea de otra insercion que salio de otro lado... cuidado con eso...

Comment: Ok, gracias colega @gbianchi

Comment: @A.Cedano nose si puedas publicar tu respuesta colega, para indicarla como aceptada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende del contexto.

Si la persona en ese contexto no existe todavía tienes que hacer dos `INSERT`, primero de la persona, luego con `LAST_INSERT_ID` recuperas el ID que se habrá asignado a la persona que se acaba de insertar y los usas junto con los otros datos que ya tienes para hacer una segunda inserción, esta vez en la tabla `Orden`.

Si la persona ya existe entonces la inserción sólo se haría en la tabla `Orden`, teniendo de ante-mano el ID de la persona, dado que ya existe.

Dicho eso, tendrías que tener cuidado con `LAST_INSERT_ID`. Hay varias discusiones sobre su fiabilidad o no, sobre todo en conexiones concurrentes.

Imaginemos este escenario:

Una base de datos de un sitio con miles o millones de usuarios al mismo tiempo creando registros. Tú eres el usuario `007` que ingresas, insertas una persona y obtienes mediante `LAST_INSERT_ID` el ID de esa fila. Pero en unos milisegundos, antes de que se realice la inserción en `Orden` 5 usuarios más hicieron inserciones ¿El `LAST_INSERT_ID` que hay en tu contexto es el de la persona que ingresaste o es el de el agente `012` (el último que realmente insertó)?

Hace un tiempo leí varias respuestas del homólogo de este sitio en inglés y las opiniones eran tan variadas que aún no tengo un criterio claro sobre ese aspecto.

Aquí te dejo los enlaces por si quieres profundizar sobre el tema:

- [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)
- [Pregunta de SO](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/21181)
- [Otra pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30959678/5587982)
- [Otra pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21185666/5587982)

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda colega, saludos .